# How can i define "DisplayErrorMessage" in this case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

This is a code that I wrote for my open button ... but I have error on "DisplayErrorMessage" part.
What should I write instead? or how can I define it in order not to have the error again.

```
protected void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFileName.Text = txtFileName.Text.Trim();
    if (txtFileName.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        string strErrorMessage = "you did Not specify file for opening!";
        DisplayErrorMessage(strErrorMessage);
    }

    string strFileName = txtFileName.Text;
    string strRootRelativePath = "~/app_data/pageContent";
    string strRootRelativePathName =
    string.Format("{0}/{1}", strRootRelativePath, strFileName);
    string strPathName = Server.MapPath(strRootRelativePathName);

    System.IO.StreamReader ostreamReader = null;

    try
    {
        ostreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(strPathName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        litPageMessages.Text = ostreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        litPageMessages.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ostreamReader != null)
        {
            ostreamReader.Dispose();
            ostreamReader= null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: better user if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFileName.Text)) instead if (txtFileName.Text == string.Empty)

Comment: ok i changed it...but my problem is not on this part...i have error on line 5 where i wrote "DisplayErrorMessage"..how can i make it ok? @Nalaka

Comment: Where is `DisplayErrorMessage` defined and what error does it throws?

Comment: can you show `DislayErrorMessage` function

Comment: it is in line 5 ... @zed

Comment: The name 'DisplayErrorMessage' does not exist in the current context ...this is the error @zed

Comment: Exactly, it doesnt exists. It's only in your mind. You have to code it.

Comment: yes you are right..i wrote this code now but still doesn't work!!! can you help me i'm a begginer :(.............  private void DisplayErrorMessage()
        {string strFileName=

          txtFileName.Text;..........this is how i wanted to define it but it doesnt work @zed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alert your error message in the browser, you could do the following.

Add a class file in your `App_Code` folder, say `Helpers.cs`
Then, open it and add the following code:

```
public class Helpers
{
    public static void DisplayErrorMessage(Page page, string msg)
    {
        string script = "<script>alert('" + msg + "');</script>";

        if (!page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("MyAlertMsgHandler"))
            page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "MyAlertMsgHandler", script);
    }
}
```

Lately, call this method from your code behind like this:

```
Helpers.DisplayErrorMessage(this.Page, "Error message details.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either create a function which takes message in the parameter and use MessageBox.Show() method to Display the error message.

or

Just Call **MessageBox.Show( this, strErrorMessage )** instead of DisplayErrorMessage(strErrorMessage);

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
void  DisplayErrorMessage(string msg)
    {
        string script = "<script>alert('" + msg + "');</script>";
        if (!Page.IsStartupScriptRegistered("myErrorScript"))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("myErrorScript", script);
        }
    }
```